# Omit properties of a class with generic type

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-generics

I'm working on a [Typescript entities library](https://github.com/insurgent-lab/ts-entity/tree/refactor/add-strict-null-check) (encoding/decoding JSON <=> Classes).

I'm trying to get the type checking right, and I successfully implemented it on my `Entity` class, but I can't get it right on my `EntityBuilder` class.

The reason is that `Entity` works with class instances, but `EntityBuilder` works with classes.

Here is a code sample ([Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false&useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99&module=5&ts=3.8.0-dev.20191224&ssl=30&ssc=59&pln=30&pc=66#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oA8Bc0B2ArgLYBGApgE4DcqG0AXroaZTSgL6qpmYAOA9hQAu0UJBgBRPEICWQgJ4AhAjJAATSoloYA9ACo92jHujLVa6GDzQy0ufOj8SAKzLARAMwr8i0CPwIKYDJoNTAhMAA6I3Q9HRjeAhIQGWA-CNk0khV1AHk8MgAeABUbTCFbNRgreQA+AAps8wBhcChcYoAaPwCgsgARcLBcXKI5Eu6Aci8fACl-PEmAH0mhfnn+RdqASg6tNDoMIQALGQhI4GO3AGtW8QA1MBS1e0actTuobbYYumBNiAiWyyBS4GrQAC8+DIAHdoE11J8IPVvlwDodoDIPNA3i02ud-nhARQCO5BJCIVDYBQKGB5BcAUISWSKNtRAD+CAyJEQPwAOb1fyBYKDCLbNEY9A6HTQGEhWwQQIhE7haAAAxmRA2eDVmOqADcwKowMkQpBoCczr9dDL-gR1H4ZEReCAHORLHg8PwMmQLDC5Md1QABYryXhkeq5FxuITbNXW9BYnEKcP8bHA+yRTXailQ6YEPDuGSbSZs5DoyUZhRZ7xahaC3oioaoisYihkISBaxV+RsSXQdg2EAQELl-vodudijWIV9UVgSwwUrS0IlkRjPAWIhkBMDmKcFAxfSGVsmMwOoj22Qu+V2WRkGCaj2WGl0xzY2fBUJDaKn+IVxJklSdJwmAhE1AAWRqEoGnApEOm6T8BiGEYxiECZoGmWttWWVZ1gWSZagAbQAXV2aBilI-Z+0tAkrmAW58UeZ5Xjg-EW13Scux6YVkIiSIiDAXh6h7edIVqC1TnOcD8iKYpYPeJFulE5sWzoA8jwMX4TGaejrkxbEF0NZ5RHxWVzV4cRfUk7wCD5Y5f0OOIEgoGRDQqEDMlEPSkWYmQXgUXFEXxME8HkMtdyTeoUzINN4UUsyAEJKUwjwCyLEsItbSUTm8OECjhCQaUEepJiRdl7QsL0RHdDwAk3Us+0lA91NQDSUCkEElHeShIhkgp6lgboEHYbYgA)):

```js
class A {
    x: number;
    z: number;
}

export class EntityBuilder {
    /**
     * Build an entity object from source data.
     */
    public static buildOne<T extends any>(buildClass: T, sourceData: Omit<T, 'fromJson'|'toJson'>): T {
        this.checkClassValidity(buildClass);

        const entity: any = new buildClass();

        if (buildClass.constructor === Array.constructor) console.log(sourceData)

        // we ensure that `fromJson` is available as this
        // could simply be annotated with `@Type(Object)`
        if (typeof entity.fromJson === 'function') {
          entity.fromJson(sourceData);
          return entity;
        } else {
          return sourceData as T // don't mind me
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build multiple entities from an array of source data.
     */
    public static buildMany<T>(buildClass: T, sourceData: Omit<T, 'fromJson'|'toJson'>[]): T[] {
        this.checkClassValidity(buildClass);

        return sourceData.map(entityData => this.buildOne<T>(buildClass, entityData));
    }

    /**
     * Check if a valid class was passed through.
     */
    private static checkClassValidity(buildClass: any) {
        if (typeof buildClass !== 'function') {
            throw new Error('Class could not be found');
        }
    }
}

EntityBuilder.buildOne(A, {})
```

the last line returns the following error:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<typeof A, "prototype">'.
  Property 'prototype' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<typeof A, "prototype">'.
```

while I expect it to tell me the second argument is missing the `x` and `z` properties.

I'm omitting `fromJson` and `toJson` as these are methods from my [`Entity` class](https://github.com/insurgent-lab/ts-entity/blob/refactor/add-strict-null-check/src/Entity.ts) that should be use as a mother class for `class A` (not included for a straightforward code example).

I could really use a hand on this, I've been on it the whole afternoon and I think I've checked pretty much every SO and Github thread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the solution is, but the way you've typed means typescript is expecting `sourceData` to be an instance of `buildClass`, not just a dictionary of its properties.

Comment: @AlexWayne actually I don't want to type a class instance but instead the class itself as first argument and an object literal containing the properties of the class as second argument, but I have found no way to type the class itself :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate your fist param (creates instance of `T`) from your second (type of `T`).

```
public static buildOne<T>(buildClass: new () => T, sourceData: Omit<T, 'fromJson'|'toJson'>): T
```

This tells typescript that you want to call `buildClass` with the `new` operator and return an instance of `T`, as `buildClass` is not itself an instance of `T`.

```
EntityBuilder.buildOne<A>(A, {})
```

You should now get the error that the empty object you're passing in is missing `x` and `z`, as you expected.

As a side note, I'm not sure it makes sense for `sourceData` to be typed as an instance of `T`, considering the point being the creation of an instance of `T`. You could also have `T` extend something that, for instance, has a `fromJson` method as opposed to `any`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `<A>` in `buildOne<A>(A, {})` be inferred?

Comment: @AlexWayne yes it could be omitted, just a habit

Comment: Wow that really was just that ... I even came across a solution like this one but I must have done something wrong with it. Thanks a lot for your insights !